# SQLAlchemy DELETE: a foreign key contraint fails

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

I have the following two tables:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_entity"

    id = Column(String(32), primary_key=True, index=True)
    email = Column(String(32))
    email_constraint = Column(String(32))
    email_verified = Column(Boolean)
    enabled = Column(Boolean)
    federation_link = Column(String(32))
    first_name = Column(String(32))
    last_name = Column(String(32))
    realm_id = Column(String(32))
    username = Column(String(32))
    created_timestamp = Column(String(32))
    service_account_client_link = Column(String(32))
    not_before = Column(Integer)
    children = relationship("Userattribute", back_populates="parent")

class Userattribute(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_attribute"

    name = Column(String(32))
    value = Column(String(32))
    id = Column(String(32), primary_key=True, index=True)
    user_id = Column(String(32), ForeignKey('user_entity.id', ondelete="CASCADE"))
    parent = relationship("User", back_populates="children")
```

I want to delete a user from the `user_entity` table by his ID:

```
[SQL: DELETE FROM user_entity WHERE user_entity.id = %s]
```

Delete implementation:

```
def delete_user(db: Session, id: str):
    return db.query(models.User).filter_by(id=id)

@app.delete("/entity/{id}", response_model=schemas.Userentity)
def del_user(id: str, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    user = crud.delete_user(db, id=id)
    user_obj = user.first()
    if user_obj is not None:
        user.delete()
        db.commit()
        return JSONResponse(content={"message": "user erfolgreich gelöscht"})
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=f"ID existiert nicht")
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Why does this fail? The expected behaviour is that when I delete a user, all user_attributes in the `user_attribute` table get also deleted. How to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce your error exactly: `user.delete()` raises an `AttributeError`.  The correct call would be `db.delete(user)` I think.

---

The deletion behaviour must also be specified in the relationship on the parent:

```py
children = relationship(
                "Userattribute",
                back_populates="parent",
                cascade="all, delete"
)
```

For efficiency, you might also want to specify `passive_deletes=True`.

See [Using foreign key ON DELETE cascade with ORM relationships](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/cascades.html#using-foreign-key-on-delete-cascade-with-orm-relationships).

Comment: thank you, but since I am using the Keycloak database, I guess there is more than I have written in my question :-/

Comment: That's why we prefer that you provide a [mre].

Comment: I know, but that DB setup had specifications I did not know of then I asked that question.